# Correctly parse PDF paragraphs with Python

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I am creating a Python script that is supposed to load a bunch of PDF files from the system, do some data analysis and output the results. The nature of the data analysis is such that I must parse the PDF by paragraph, and for every paragraph I must iterate over every phrase check if some conditions are met.

I am currently parsing using Tika. And this is the way I am evaluating paragraphs.

This is what I am currently doing, I am loading the content, then, replace every occurrence of one or more newlines with a unique string. Replace every regular newline with a space, replace that unique string with a double new line. I did this so it's more clear which newline delimits a paragraph. Then I proceed to extract paragraphs and return the list of paragraphs with no dupes (Tika sometimes duplicates stuff).

```py
def getpdfcontent(path):
    pdf_content = extract_pdf(path)
    text = re.sub(r"\n{2,}", "<131313>", pdf_content['content'])
    text = text.replace("\n", " ")
    text = text.replace("<131313>", "\n\n")
    paragraphs = extractparagraphs(text.splitlines())
    return removeduplicates(paragraphs)
```

This is how I extract paragraphs. I check if the current line is empty, an if the current paragraph has something in it, and I append it to a list.

```py
def extractparagraphs(lines):
    current = ""
    paragraphs = []
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip():
            if current.strip():
                paragraphs.append(current)
                current = ""
            continue
        current += line.strip()
    return paragraphs
```

This is how I get pharses, I might add !? to the split too.

```py
def getphrases(document):
    phrases = []
    phr = document.split(".")
    phrases.extend(phr)
    return phrases
```

Now my priority is to know if I can improve the parsing ? 
If not, is there any optimisations I can do ?

Comment: Unless pdfs are tagged, there is no concept of a paragraph in them. At best you have the concept of lines. Thus, your requirement to *parse the PDF by paragraph* generally is merely achievable using heuristics and, therefore, not for sure, merely with a certain probability.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer :) !

Comment: The heuristics for this is quite complicated. However, if you can handle Java, there are libraries available that will deconstruct the page content and do a very good job of inferring paragraphs, sentences, and words, in proper reading order from untagged (or tagged) PDF.